# save variable from if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

Couldn't find an answer on google because I didn't know how to phrase is.

I have a regular function as below and would like to update the variable *number* in the first if statement. I've tried all sorts of combos but nothing works.

```
int main()
{
  int apple, number;
  cout << "Enter you number"<< endl;
  cin >> apple;

  if (apple == 1){
   number = 2;
  }

  else {
    number = 3;
cout << number << endl;
}
```

How would I change the above so I get 2 to output to the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just write `if (apple ==1)`.

Comment: The code you posted will (always) update `apple`. How are you determining that it isn't?

Comment: What do you mean about "but nothing works" exactly? What error and output did you get?

Comment: I simplified the question as my actual code is much longer, so to avoid all the code reading and debugging, I just created another example of what i was looking.

Comment: I just wanted to know away to save apple to the value of 2, so that the cout outside the if loop, can see it.

Comment: @songyuanyao: I meant that the variable isn't being save in the if loop so that the cout statement outside of it prints the value 2.

Comment: I can't imagine what you're doing that could possibly cause this to not work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

```
if (apple == 1)
```

instead of

```
if (apple = 1)
```

`==` is used for comparison. Also to note that your code will always assign the value `2` to the variable `apple` as in your condition you are not comparing rather you are assigning. So in your case **[the output](https://ideone.com/64firg)** will always be 2.

Comment: i changed that, sorry for the silly mistake. I also updated the code to a better example.

Comment: So then how could I make the main "number" variable change to 2 or 3 and have is show in the cout?